# GLSL and glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES) not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

This code only renders a dodecahedron and completely ignores the `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)` block:

```
glutSolidDodecahedron();
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glNormal3f(1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(11, 0, 0);
glNormal3f(0, 1, 1);
glVertex3f(-11, 0, 0);
glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 11);
glEnd();
```

The two shaders are quite simplistic:

the vertex shader:

```
varying vec3 normal;
void main()
{   
gl_Position = ftransform();
gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
gl_BackColor = gl_Color;
normal =  gl_Normal;
normal = gl_NormalMatrix  * normal;
}
```

and the frag:

```
uniform vec3 lightDir;
varying vec3 normal;
void main()
{
    float intensity = dot(lightDir, normal);
    gl_FragColor =  0.5 * (1.5 + intensity) * gl_Color;
}
```

While `glutSolidX` type of functions work well with this example (based on the [Lightouse3D](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/hello-world-in-glsl/) tutorial), how can one quickly draw triangles that change coordinates from frame to frame (I tried arrays and GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW, but that's too much work as compared to the old "fixed pipeline" approach). I saw other people still managing to use `glBegin(..); glEnd();` blocks with GLSL shaders successfully, so it must be possible. What could be missing?

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you tried outputting a solid color from the fragment shader?

Comment: Are you sure it completely ignores the `glBegin/glEnd` block intead of just rendering it outside the viewing frustum or back-face culling the triangle? The former would be really strange (or actually impossible), since `glutSolid...` is also nothing more than a simple `glBegin/glEnd` block.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck the shaders are compiling and linking without any errors. Setting a solid colour works, it ignores the pseudo-lighting computation in the fragment.

Comment: @ChrsitanRau I think I saw some odd artefacts (in the sense that some parts of the solid objects were, from certain angles covered by a triangle like shape). What could I do to avoid the incorrect culling? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coordinates of the vertices of the triangle in the glBegin/glEnd block are

```
 11, 0,  0
-11, 0,  0
  0, 0, 11
```

which means it lies completely flat in the view. This is like viewing a sheet of paper from such a hard angle, it becomes a line. Because triangles have no thickness, not even this line is drawn and the triangle seems invisible.

Comment: Alright, this might be it, thanks.. I'll check all my coordinates and if this is the source of all "evil" I'll also accept the answer. Many thanks for this observation.. +1

Comment: It may also be, that the triangle is facing away from the view and backfaces get culled (like mentioned in the questions comments). In this case, the order in which the vertices are submitted has to be reversed, in order to flip the triangle to the correct direction.

Comment: Well it answered my initial question: it's possible to render triangles this way. The fact that none of my normally computed triangles don't get render, regardless of the orientation is another point of investigation. Good work spotting the almost "degenerate" case for that triangle.

Comment: It was orientation independent, nevertheless, it was because of the excessive view angle.